# show-hide shipping methods (shipping options) dynamically according to customer group

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.8

I have 3 to 5 active shipping methods in my store. I want to set these shipping methods dynamically based on customers group. Here is example:

available Shipping methods for customer group-1: **Shipping Method 1**, **Shipping Method 3**, **Shipping Method 4**, so on...

available Shipping methods for customer group-2: **Shipping Method 2**, **Shipping Method 3**

Please let me know how can I listed & unlisted all active shipping methods according to customer groups on checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

This will require you to customize your code. The best way is to use a module like below

[Customer Group Checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/netz98magento/extension/7590/n98_customergroupcheckout)

Also creating Shopping cart price rule may help you.